# CSS hover is affecting sibling elements?

Tags: html, css, onhover

I have created the following section as part of a website I'm currently working on.

[image: http://piclair.com/data/rarn7.jpg]

When the social media icons below the job title are hovered over with the cursor, the CSS is supposed to generate a border around the icons individually, without affecting anything else on this entire section. However, upon the border appearing, the other gray boxes seem to be getting a `margin-top`-like effect to them.

This is what's described in the previous paragraph:
[image: http://piclair.com/data/djqpw.jpg]

What I'm trying to achieve is the same effect as seen in the latter photo, only without the other div's being pushed down. The effect does look nice to some extent, but I would like to know what's causing it and how I would be able to avoid it.

This is the structure of one of those boxes, as an example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-span-3 crew-member">
      <img src="imgs/avatar1.jpg" alt="" class="img-circle">
      <div class="name">John Blue</div>
      <div class="job-title">Web & Graphics Designer</div>
      <div class="social-icons">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And as requested, here is a JSFIDDLE with the hover problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/c9zwecha/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your HTML **and** your CSS in ths snippet, or in a jsfiddle? Thanks..

Comment: This has nothing to do with your html, please provide your css and relevant javascript.

Comment: It is just up to the css. There can be 2 issues: 1. You've set the social_icons:hover{ margin-top } or -> 2. The margin of the child affects the entire parent element (maybe if you used display: table or something)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c9zwecha/ though it's not a 100% duplicate, it's enough to solve the problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that each *crew-member* is displayed as `inline-block`. Then, when you hover the icon and increase it's size, the line-height of the full stuff is increased and the other members *slide down*.

To prevent this, you need to align every member to the top like this.

```
.who .crew-container .crew-member {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/c9zwecha/1/

Comment: Here it is in full screen for better visualization of the result: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/c9zwecha/1/embedded/result/

Comment: This is indeed the answer, thank you very much Joaquín O. :)